# High dockerd sys CPU usage

Tags: docker

We are in the process of trying to migrate a windows desktop app to docker. We have created a light-weight Ubuntu based container with wine + vnc and the app is running well.

We need to run a large quantity of these apps on a given host, circa 500 - 600 per host. The host its self is a high spec, 4 x 8 Core CPU.

When testing under load, dockerd is using a very high amount of the sys cpu, and by high i mean for every 1% of user CPU in use, its using around 1% of sys cpu.

The problem this is causing is that compared to running the same app under Windows / Hyper-V, we can only get 50% quantity wise of the same application running, which is clearly an issue. If we were to factor out the sys CPU load, then they are pretty much equal.

Networking wise, we are using MACVLAN where each container has its own IP address that is mapped directly into the network.

First of all, is this normal for dockerd to be using so much CPU?

Cheers in advance!